# Deleting a column of a DataFrame without deleting the original in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm not sure how to explain the question so just look at the simple code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2], "B": [3, 4]})
y = x
del y ["A"]
print(x)
print(y)
```

Output

```
   B
0  3
1  4
   B
0  3
1  4
```

As you can see, deleting a column from y deletes it from x too, is there any way to delete the column from y without deleting it on x too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `x` and `y` both reference the same underlying object.  If you want to make a copy of `x`, you can use:

```
y = x.copy()
```

Example:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2], "B": [3, 4]})
y = x.copy()
del y["A"]
print(x)
print('-'*6)
print(y)

# returns:
   A  B
0  1  3
1  2  4
------
   B
0  3
1  4
```

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work, it returns:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***", line 7, in <module>
    del b ["A"]
TypeError: 'method' object does not support item deletion

Comment: in your example, @Ryunaq it works. maybe you should update your example.

Comment: Yep it worked, I forgot to add the parenthesis to .copy, my bad, thanks!